# How do I set variable `remote.pushDefault` for an existing repository in Magit?

Tags: magit

In an existing repository, how do I set the local variable `remote.pushDefault`?

Short of doing it manually:

```
git config remote.pushDefault origin
```

I'm not looking to set it up for new repositories, or for origins that I add through magit--I want to do this on existing repos that I've already cloned somehow.

Is there an easy way to access this configuration through magit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fetch -> configure menu: <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

Cycle through remotes using <kbd>P</kbd>.

N.B.: That configure menu is primarily for configuring a specific branch, but it also offers some options that affect the entire repository (under "repository defaults").